# Unity hangs when opening C# Script

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Every time I try to open a C# Script inside Unity, it immediately hangs and doesn't even open Visual Studio, this started happening after I updated Visual Studio 2017 twice, the first one was an incomplete installation since my computer restarted then the second one was completed version.

Unity still works normally for all things except opening a C# script. I tried changing the External Tools Preferences in the Edit  between Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2017 (Community) but both did nothing.

When Unity hangs, I can only use Task Manager to close it and MonoDevelop isn't one of the options in the External Tools Preferences

Comment: Uninstall your visual studio, then open up unity hub (install if you don't have), and in the versions tab go onto the three dots to modify components of you unity version, choose visual studio and let it install. This has proven to be the fastest way for me :D

Comment: make sure your visual studio has the unity addon bit (mines decided it needs to update so cant get you the actual name of it) installed (visual studio tools for unity), also make the assumption that the visual studio link you see in the editor is incorrect and add a new one by browse to add your visual studio and see if that then works, or add notepad, just to see if that works.

Comment: @Musaka, I tried doing what you said but it didn't work. I installed VS 2019 through the Unity Hub and also changed the External Tools Preferences to become Visual Studio 2019 but Unity still hangs

Answer (score 1):

Can you open Visual Studio when Unity is not open? Which version of Unity are you using for your project? Are you using Unity Hub to manage your versions?

**Steps to try:**

- Reinstall VS (update to 2019 optional)
- Close all background services related to VS and Unity.

If all else fails, you can clean the registry before reinstalling.

Comment: I can open Visual Studio just fine and anytime. I'm using Unity Hub to manage my versions for Unity and I'm currently using Unity 2019.2.3f1.
I'll try reinstalling VS 2017, I'll update if it works but it might take a little long.

Comment: This is more suited as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: I myself use VS 2019 with no problems. I do recommend upgrading. Also, silly question but have you restarted your computer since this problem occured? Sometimes the communication between Unity and VS fails due to processes in the background, especially if you had a failed update/install as you mentioned.

@Coder, first post on Stackoverflow, didn't know but thanks for the tip!

Comment: @Finn, I tried restarting the computer and it actually worked. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall both Unity, VS and any dependency that you have installed. Then go to Hub and download your required version with all the required dependencies.

Doing this will remove any inconsistency and also you will not have to do the external tool reference yourself.